# Get RecyclerView child Views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to get all the Views of RecyclerView items but it seems I can get only the first one. I am fetching the Views like this:

```
LinearLayoutManager manager = (LinearLayoutManager) rv.getLayoutManager();
List<View> list = new ArrayList<View>();

for(int i = 0; i < manager.getItemCount(); i ++ ) {
  manager.scrollToPosition(i);

  View view = manager.findViewByPosition(i);

  if(view == null) {
    Log.i("Null Check", "Null: " + i);
  }

  list.add(view);
}
```

The problem is that I fetch the first View in RecyclerView all the time. If I have 10 items, first item will be fetched and other 9 items will be logged as null. It's like `scrollToPosition(i)` is not working correctly.

This is `scrollToPosition(i)` javadoc:

> Scroll the RecyclerView to make the position visible. RecyclerView
>   will scroll the minimum amount that is necessary to make the target
>   position visible. If you are looking for a similar behavior to
>   android.widget.ListView.setSelection(int) or
>   android.widget.ListView.setSelectionFromTop(int, int), use
>   scrollToPositionWithOffset(int, int). **Note that scroll position change
>   will not be reflected until the next layout call.**

I am worried because of this last sentence. What do you think how can I solve this?

Comment: As someone else also asked, why are you trying to do this? If you want all views, what is the point of using RecyclerView?

Also, yes, you are not getting new views because RecyclerView will not scroll to the new position until a new layout pass happens.

Answer (score 3):

Retrieve RecyclerView children through the assigned `RecyclerView.Adapter` not the layout manager. The layout manager assists in laying out children views (ie. measuring and layout) but you should be consulting the [Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html) assigned to manage the RecyclerView's data and not its layout manager.

Comment: Thank you but how to get a View from adapter?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do with the Views? The goal of RecyclerView/ListViews are such that you provide the data set and bind the data to the views through the Adapter; you would override `onBindViewHolder` to accomplish this. The idea is so that you are only responsible for updating/managing the data set while letting the Adapter handle arranging the views. See [Creating Lists and Cards](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html). Or edit your post above with more code (including your adapter and why you need a list of views)